# SQL: Multiple, connected filter (2 columns)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to filter a table for specifc order IDs that I have in another 'blacklist' table. The problem is, that order IDs are only unqique within a country, so I would need to have a connection between order ID and country ID. E.g. Filter out order ID 12345, but only if the ID occurs in the US, but not Mexico. The 'blacklist' table includes this information, but I don't know how I can filter the data table appropriately, as a simple AND statement is not sufficient in this case.

Thanks!

Daniel

edit: So, I have added an example at the bottom.

The expected output from this should then be

```
100 10000001
200 10000001
300 10000001 xx filtered out
100 10000002 xx filtered out
200 10000002 xx filtered out
300 10000002
100 10000003
200 10000003
300 10000003
100 10000004 xx filtered out
200 10000004
300 10000004 xx filtered out
```

Both the suggested solutions helped solve the problem - thanks a lot!

Solution 1 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0ab6/3
Solution 2 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0ab6/4

Comment: Please supply the table definitions, some sample data and the expected output based on that data. **edit** your question and format the information properly

Comment: How about adding your schema to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15) so we can see the tables and play a bit with them? Just the schema and maybe a few rows of data would be nice. :)

Comment: Sure, give me a minute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get you completely, but in MySQL you can filter by pairs, e.g.

```
order_id  country   total_price
4523   ES        6 
4524   ES        9 
4525   FR        7
```

You can query then by order and country like this:

```
SELECT * FROM order
WHERE (order_id, country) 
   IN (SELECT id, country FROM blacklist WHERE country = 'ES')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works and looks to be the simplest solution - I didn't know this was actually possible. Apologies if it should have been obvious, I just recently started with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1
    FROM blacklist b
    WHERE o.country = b.country 
      AND o.ID = b.ID)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! I ultimately went with tokenizer's solution as it gives me the same result and is shorter. Any advantages over using 'EXISTS' rather than 'WHERE'?

Comment: I use `Exists` after `WHERE` instead of using `IN` ;).